# ASP.NET WebForms - routing gives 'page not found error '

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I am using asp.net routing and getting a 404 error.

If I do not use an `id` value then I can see page.

But I want to pass `id`data with route and getting 404 Page Not Found error.

Not sure why we see error when we want to use parameters.

With Parameters (404 File or Directory not found error)

```
 routes.MapPageRoute( "Product", "product/{id}", "~/Pages/Product.aspx" );
```

Without Parameters (Page Works)

```
 routes.MapPageRoute( "Product", "product", "~/Pages/Product.aspx" );
```

**UPDATED NOTE:** I have tested all routes if i add product/{id}, contact/{id} or etc. It causes all the same 404 error.

**URL:** test.com/product > WORKS 
         test.com/product/{id} > NOT FOUND

Answer (score 1):

try this with * query values

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
       "Product",
        "product/{Id}/{*queryvalues}",
        "~/Pages/Product.aspx"
    );
```

Comment: I'm only passing product id value with route. @Ameya Deshpande